# additive or multiplicative model?

Tags: feature-selection, model-selection

let's say if I have two scores $x_1^i$ and $x_2^i$ for each data point $i$, and I need to make a final score/loss function out of it.

Should I use a weighted sum $w_1 x_1^i + w_2 x_2^i$, or their multiplication $x_1^i x_2^i$? (of course loss is the minus score)

I think multiplication is addition in a different sense? because $\log x_1 x_2 = \log x_1 + \log x_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of multiplication, loss of each point will interact with other. For eg: if loss of point 1 is 0 and point 2 is 3. Then total loss is 0. However, this is not the case.

In case you want to magnify the loss you can take exponential of each loss. Still loss minimum will be at the same point as you will get without exponential

Loss function objective is to find minima of total loss . Total loss can be sum average over all instances .it should be representative of all the instances

Comment: yes, thank you. I know the last point. I mean there are two scores $x_1^i$, $x_2^i$ for each data point $i$

Comment: What does score mean ? Are there two possible model outputs ?

Comment: well, if you have to ask specifically, for example, movie recommendation. A user `a` has a rating for move `b` (if there isn't a rating between `a` and `b`, you can generate it using collaborative filtering). And you can compute a score using text similarity between user `a`'s profile and movie `b`'s descriptions. Now you have two scores, the users' ratings and text similarities, how will you recommend top-k movies for a user? (note that a user have only rated a few movies. most ratings are generated by collaborative filtering)

Comment: I will do this . Prepare evaluation or test data. Prepare possible combinations of score: 0% to 100% weight for one score. Find accuracy for all combinations. Take the weight combinations  with highest accuracy.  Multiplying scores will not work.